# Start animation in RemoteViews

Tags: android, notifications, android-remoteview

I made a notification with a custom view, I need to run animation on one of the children but as you know `RemoteViews` doesn't allow to have direct access to the desired view (to invoke `start` method on its background), Does any one know how to access to the view or invoke mentioned method on its drawable ?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, fortunately, I found a workaround:

1. replace the view you want to animate with a `ProgressBar`
2. set `indeterminateDrawable` the animation drawable you want, No need to invoke the start method!

Comment: Smart solution!